# how can a person add abbreviated names for unicode character names in Emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs, utf-8, elisp

Using emacs-24.

Some unicode names are quite long.  Some characters have more than one name depending on the context. I would like to add some abbreviations/synonyms.  How?

This approach is not so bad, but I have problems with shorter names that alias with longer ones, and it is non-standard, i.e. not consistent with the way other names are entered:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g all") "∀")
```

The approach of putting characters on keys has problems in Emacs, partly because the keymap is already overloaded:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-~") (kbd "¬"))
```

As a secondary question, I am curious as to why this confuses emacs (give it a try):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g neg") "¬")
```

What I would like is to hook the abbreviations into the current emacs method for entering unicode characters by name.  (I've been using C-x 8 RET name RET - though wish there was a method to do this in fewer key strokes.)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can easily define a command that inserts a given character (or that chooses from some small set of characters rather than from the entire universe of Unicode characters).

   Library [**`ucs-cmds.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ucs-cmds.el) can help with this. When you use `C-x 8 RET` with a negative prefix arg (e.g. `C--`), it not only inserts the char you choose but it creates a command to insert the char - the command name is the same as the char name. And you can quickly create such commands for whole ranges or other sets of characters (e.g. by matching a regexp). You can of course rename commands to whatever you like, including shorter versions.

   But you already know how to bind a key to a keyboard macro that inserts a given character, as you have shown. If it helps to provide a named command for that then `ucs-cmds.el` can help.
2. You can also just do that yourself individually, using, for example:

   ```
   (defun neg (&optional n)
     "Insert \"¬\".  With prefix arg N, insert N times."
     (interactive "p")
     (dotimes (ii n) (insert "¬")))

   (global-set-key (kbd "C-x g neg") 'neg)
   ```
3. But you apparently are not very interested in dedicated commands that insert particular characters, and you want to be able to use `C-x 8 RET` but to type an abbreviation for a character name when it prompts you, instead of trying to match the real character name.

   For that, [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) can help. When you use `C-x 8 RET` you can match the character name or its code point (or the character itself - useful when the char is easy to type and you want to know its name or code point). You can match any combination of these at the same time.

   Matching can be substring, regexp, pcompletion or any of several kinds of fuzzy matching, and you can change the matching behavior on the fly. So you can get the effect of the abbreviations you are asking for, provided you abbreviate in a way that corresponds to matching.
4. As for your question about `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g neg") "¬")`: I think it is a bug. Consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. This is the error that it raises:

   > After 0 kbd macro iterations: user-error: No M-x tags-search or M-x tags-query-replace in progress

Comment: I sent the bug report.  What I had in mind was to find where C-x 8 is bound and then to add some code to catch my abbreviations before running the actual reg-x search you mention.

Comment: `C-h k C-x 8 RET` tells you: "*C-x 8 RET (translated from C-x 8 <return>) runs the command
insert-char (found in global-map), which is an interactive built-in
function in `C source code`.*" But you can bind `C-x 8 RET` to your own command that does what you want interactively, and then calls `insert-char` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several modes around which  provide simplified input for symbols  needed by math and logic. For example agda2-mode. http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> What I would like is to hook the abbreviations into the current emacs method for entering unicode characters by name. (I've been using C-x 8 RET name RET - though wish there was a method to do this in fewer key strokes.)

What the OP is asking for is:
a) To use the emacs function 'insert-char' with its built-in shortcut 'C-x 8 RET', and
b) To use an alias for completion in the interactive minibuffer for 'insert-char' input.

The issue is that the minibuffer for 'insert-char' has its own TAB completion.  If you want to insert the greek small letter epsilon (ε) using TAB completion, you have to input a minimum number of keystrokes like this: "greek" TAB "sm" TAB "l" TAB "ep".  Even if you have an alias for epsilon in your 'init.el' configuration file like this: '("eps" "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON")', the minibuffer will not automatically recognize it.

You can still use the alias for epsilon you have in your 'init.el' file using a second function 'expand-abbrev'.  Using the method described in the OP, you can get an 'ε' by using "C-x 8 RET" (or "M-x insert-char"), entering your alias "eps", then call 'expand-abbrev' ("M-x expand abbrev") and return.  This will expand your alias for the 'insert-char' function.  (There is also a 'C-x' shortcut for 'M-x expand-abbrev'.)

Like the OP, I prefer this method over (or in addition to) automatic alias replacement.  If you have something in your config file like this:

```
;; a quick way to insert unicode characters by code point or name
(global-set-key [f8] 'insert-char)

;; call 'expand-abbrev', especially in the 'insert-char' input minibuffer
(global-set-key [f9] 'expand-abbrev)

;; abbreviate unicode names
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("ueps" "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON")
    ("Ueps" "ε")
    ("ugsl" "GREEK SMALL LETTER ")
    ("uforall" "FOR ALL")
    ("Uforall" "∀")
    ))
;; see .emacs.d/abbrev_defs
;; M-x edit-abbrevs

;; turn on abbrev mode by default
(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
```

, you have two ways to type an epsilon.  You can let emacs replace the alias "Ueps" automatically, or you can use seven keystrokes "[f8]ueps[f9]RET".  (Actually there are four ways here.)

As the OP suggests, it is somewhat impractical to have aliases (or key-bindings) for every single special character.  That is why it makes sense to use 'insert-char' with 'expand-abbrev'.  If you want to insert a less commonly used greek letter like omicron 'ο', for instance, you do not need a special alias; you can expand an alias like 'ugsl' to "GREEK SMALL LETTER ", and enter "omicron" (or "omi" + TAB).